# KafkaStreams 2.3 application does not become stable after migrating to Kafka streams 2.6

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My question is:   When migrating (offline) an existing Kafka streams application from v2.3 -> v2.6 do you have to change anything in the config?

The Kafka Brokers run on Kafka server 2.6

Our Kafka Streams application does not seem to behave after upgrading the Kafka streams library from v2.3 to v2.6 without other changes. We just build the application with new kafka streams 2.6 library, without other changes.

I expected it to behave the same as with the 2.3 library but it doesn't.

We are consuming messages with 3 pods from a topic with 30 partitions, then we do a .mapValues() that might take about ~10-500ms per message, that's a lot but nothing spectacular.  We tried to get it working by playing with following parameters, but we did not succeed.

```
session.timeout.ms=30000
max.poll.records=20
num.stream.threads=10
```

After a while (10 - 15) the consumergroup might become stable for a few seconds but with only 5 or 6 members and then obviously starts to rebalance again.
We do not use kafka streams static membership at the moment. First we would like to get it stable without.

consumer config value are:

```
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [pp5-kafka-acc-headless.pp5-acc:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = HeadEndPushServiceLowNetinium-211cbe23-50b2-4942-95f1-b93567d145c2-StreamThread-8-consumer
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 200000
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = HeadEndPushServiceLowNetinium
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 5
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsPartitionAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 30000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

With v2.3 we manage easily to process 800 messages/second. With v2.6 we can only process 50 messages/second because it is continuously rebalancing.

UPDATE:  After setting the session.timeout.ms = 180000 (3 minutes) and introducing the group.instance.id (=POD_NAME) the application seems to get more stable with 30 threads in total.
Sometime it takes only 2 minutes to get stable after deleting a pod. Sometimes it can take 10 minutes to get stable.  But it seems to get stable in the end and during the rebalancing the throughput is higher than before.

Comment: After setting the session.timeout.ms = 180000 (3 minutes) and introducing the group.instance.id (=POD_NAME) the application seems to get more stable with 30 threads in total.
Sometime it takes only 2 minutes to get stable after deleting a pod. Sometimes it can take 10 minutes to get stable.  But it seems to get stable in the end and during the rebalancing the throughput is higher than before.

Comment: The question remains that why does it work under Kafka streams client 2.3 and doesn't it work under Kafka streams client 2.6?